# Reutilización de contenedores en Docker - Usar un mismo servicio para varios proyectos

Tags: docker, docker-compose

##### ¡Hola, qué tal!

Habitualmente, uso docker compose para levantar servicios que uso para mis proyectos en los que trabajo con Laravel. Mi docker-compose.yml, generalmente, tiene tres servicios: uno que se basa en una imagen de php para la **app**, uno de **MySql**, y otro de **Nginx**.

Cuando debo trabajar en un nuevo proyecto simultáneamente, levanto los mismos servicios, creando otra vez los mismos contenedores, para Php, Nginx, y MySql, pero exponiendo diferentes puertos.

Mi duda es, ¿debería tener un solo contenedor para Nginx y otro para MySql, y reutilizar esos contenedores en varios proyectos, o es correcto crear contenedores para cada proyecto en el que trabaje, aunque los servicios sean los mismos (mysql y nginx)? ¿Qué sería lo más recomendable?

Comment: Buenas, creo que realmente el metodo de despliegue no supondria ningun problema, trabaja de la forma que mas comodo te sientas, Si te sientes mas comodo abriendo nuevos contenedores por proyecto es una buena forma de trabajar, reutilizar contenedores mantendra tus puertos libres pero si estas habituado a trabajar con diferentes quiza al principio te lies un poco. No veo mayor problema en usar una u otra forma. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, la filosofía de Docker dice que un contenedor debe tener un solo propósito, debe ejecutar un solo proceso y deben ser efímeros. Esto implica que deberías desplegar todos los contenedores que sean necesarios, aunque se repitan. El propio Docker hace su parte deduplicando las capas idénticas de las imágenes.

Sin embargo, en algunos casos, podría ser interesante reutilizar contenedores, sobre todo, para poder ahorrar recursos de cómputo. Por ejemplo, yo suelo usar una base de datos distinta para cada proyecto, lo que facilita su administración, backup, escalado, etc, pero solo un nginx haciendo de reverse proxy.